# verify digital signed email with attachment "the hash value is not correct"

Tags: c#, email, digital-signature, exchangewebservices

I am trying to verify the signature of a digitally signed email. It know the signature is correct, because outlook verifies it. I am using SignedCms to perform the validation

I have the following message:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";
    micalg=sha1; boundary="boundary1"

--boundary1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="boundary2"

--boundary2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

some text in the body
of the message



--boundary2
Content-Type: application/something;
    name="somefile.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="somefile.txt"

FkrMjIwOjE1OCdRVFkrMjIwOjE3NidRVFkrMjIwOjE5MydRVFkrMjIwOjIwNydR
VFkrMjIwOjIyMidRVFkrMjIwOjIzNCdRVFkrMjIwOjI0NSdRVFkrMjIwOjI1OCdRVFkrMjIwOjI2
NidRVFkrMjIwOjI3NydRVFkrMjIwOjI4NSdRVFkrMjIwOjI5MSdRVFkrMjIwOjI5OCdRVFkrMjIw
OjMwMidRVFkrMjIwOjMwNidRVFkrMjIwO
--boundary2--

--boundary1
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIIEAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIATCCB/0CAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3
DQEHAaCCBW4wggVqMIIEUqADAgECAg4YHgABAAIO2xMJhvDULzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQUFADB8MQswCQYDVQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UEChMTVEMgVHJ1c3RDZW50ZXIgR21i


--boundary1--
```

and I am having huge trouble verifying the signature for it.

This is how I attempt to do it:
EmailMessage message = results.ElementAt(13) as EmailMessage;
            message.Load();

```
        var attachments = message.Attachments;
        foreach (var attachment in attachments)
        {
            var fAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
            fAttachment.Load();
            string fullMailData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fAttachment.Content);
            FileToolbox.WriteStringToFile(@"C:\BeforeDecoding.txt", fullMailData);
            var lines = fullMailData.Split('\n');
            string signature = "";
            string dataPlain = "";
            //These line numbers do not correspond to the example, 
            //because it is altered to hide the real email
            for (int i = 12 - 1; i <= 13 - 1; i++)
            {
                dataPlain += lines[i];
            }
            //These line numbers do not correspond to the example
            //because it is altered to hide the real email
            for (int i = 56 - 1; i <= 99 - 1; i++)
                {
                    signature += lines[i];
                }

            var signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataPlain)));
            signedCms.Decode(base64_decode(signature));
            signedCms.CheckHash();
            signedCms.CheckSignature(true);
```

So in the above example I only use the body with text/plain to checksignature. I have also attempted the following sections:

1. Everything from --boundary1 until --boundary1 appears again.
2. Only the base64 encrypted body part (which is then base64 decoded)
3. A merge of the 2 bodies
4. I have attempted keeping the \r and \n values
5. I have attempted keeping only the \r values

Every one returns with invalid hash value.

What am I doing wrong? which part of the message should I pass to new SignedCms()?

**Extra comment to the solution**
Since PKCS#7/CMS messages from web methods are always detached signedcms should be instantiated with detached = true according to this [somewhat acceptable source](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/46_2009_6_0_0_793061/Dotnet-2-0-PCKS-CheckSignature-Error.htm)

```
public SignedCms(
    ContentInfo contentInfo,
    bool detached
)
```

For my MWE I saved the full file content to a file and then manually removed some lines. I did not do the string split up (yet...). So my MWE ended up like this:

```
    var fullMessageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\fAttachment_content.txt");
    var isoEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    var fullMessageString = isoEncoding.GetString(fullMessageBytes);

    var messageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\message_body.txt");
    var messageBytesString = isoEncoding.GetString(messageBytes);

    var signatureStringReadIn = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\certToReadIn.txt");
    var signatureStringReadInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureStringReadIn);

    var signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageBytes), true);
    signedCms.Decode(signatureStringReadInBytes);
    signedCms.CheckSignature(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Everything from --boundary1 until --boundary1 appears again* but don't forget that the crlf after the leading --boundary1 and the crlf before the trailing --boundary1 respectively are part of boundary and, therefore, must not be hashed.

For a sample look into the specification [RFC 5751](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751#section-3.4) section 3.4.3.3. *Sample multipart/signed Message.*

If i were you, though, I would try **not** to transform the content from bytes to string and back to bytes. Instead i would work in a byte array. Your transformations always come with the risk of changing the content.

Comment: So it is this part: http://pastebin.com/1ydeGSD5 correct? and I am to keep all the \r\n\t\whatever correct?
Great example however it does not contain attachments.

It is not an option to keep it in bytes, because I need to know where to begin and stop to only get the data to digest. Any other suggestion on this?

Comment: *It is not an option to keep it in bytes, because I need to know where to begin and stop to only get the data to digest.* you can parse byte arrays, too... concerning attachments: they don't make a difference. Concerning the pastebin paste: it looks good at first glance. Whether it's correct can only be decided setting the actual bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I just got it working. I have yet to find a clever way to get the message part, but I have a MWE :)

Answer (score 0):

@mkl - Unfortunately, I can't add a comment yet but I was curious where in [RFC 5751](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751#page-26) it indicated that \r\n after the leading boundary and before the first reoccurrence of that boundary were part of the boundary.  It works, but just wondering how that was known.

Comment: Well, one place indicating that is the sample I referenced in my answer which explicitly shows the bytes of the content that is digested, and these bytes do not contains the line breaks mentioned. Apart from that this is not defined in RFC 5751 but in the underlying MIME specifications, e.g. [RFC 2046](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046), especially [section 5.1.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1). That been said, strictly speaking you probably should have made this a question in its own right, not an answer to this old question.